# JAXB bindings of complex type to new classname

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm trying to map the following to a new class name via the maven-jaxb2-plugin.

I have this element that exists in two XSD's in the project (different namespaces).

I want to map this instance to a different classname so that it compiles.

```
<xs:complexType name="ResponseCommonData">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RequestID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="BusinessError" form="qualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="BusinessErrorCommonData"/>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="BusinessCommonData">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Code" type="xs:string" form="unqualified" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The bindings.xjb I have is...

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="CFRV2.0.0.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
       <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='ResponseCommonData']">
                 <jaxb:property  name="CFRResponseCommonData" />
       </jaxb:bindings>
       <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='BusinessCommonData']">
                 <jaxb:property  name="CFRBusinessCommonData" />
       </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The error I get is this...

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: A class/interface with the same name
"com.ResponseCommonData" is already in use. 
Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

If I remove the inner element BusinessError from ResponseCommonData then the JAXB will proceed on, but giving me a similar message about another complex type class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jaxb:class` instead of `jaxb:property`.